# Javascript/PHP countdown timer that updates every second and counts down to a specific date and time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So the code below is the code that I was able to work with so far; however, doesn't do exactly what I need it to do.

I want to be able to call a function (aka: sundayDelta() ), however, I would love to be able to define the day of week and time of day I want the function to use in the countdown inside the calling of the function. I'm not sure if this is possible...but I was thinking something like this

sundayDelta(1,1000) which would turn into Day of Week Sunday and time of day: 1000 (10:00am). Not sure if something like this is even possible; however, I'm hoping it is. I plan on having multiple countdowns going on the same page just appearing at different times of day.

When the countdown finishes, I want it to refresh a div (doesn't matter what name the div has)

I would also love to be able to incorporate PHP server time into this that way everyone is seeing the correct countdown no matter where they are.

Any help would be great! Thanks for your input!

```
function plural(s, i) {
  return i + ' ' + (i > 1 ? s + 's' : s);
}

function sundayDelta(offset) {
  // offset is in hours, so convert to miliseconds
  offset = offset ? offset * 20 * 20 * 1000 : 0;
  var now = new Date(new Date().getTime() + offset);
  var days = 7 - now.getDay() || 7;
  var hours = 10 - now.getHours();
  var minutes =  now.getMinutes() - 00 ;
  var seconds =  now.getSeconds()- 00;
    if (hours < 0){
      days=days-1;
    }
    var positiveHours= -hours>0 ? 24-(-hours) : hours;
  return [plural('day', days),
          plural('hour', positiveHours),
          plural('minute', minutes), 
          plural('second', seconds)].join(' ');
}

// Save reference to the DIV
$refresh = $('#refresh');

$refresh.text('This page will refresh in ' + sundayDelta());

// Update DIV contents every second
setInterval(function() {
  $refresh.text('This page will refresh in ' + sundayDelta());
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I'd be okay with using data- variables as well to pass the date/time.  I just want it to work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I make flexible text for intervals, I like to subtract out until nothing is left. That way you only show the non-0 values:

```
function sundayDelta(target_date) {
    var now = new Date();
    var offset = Math.floor((Date.parse(target_date) - now.valueOf()) / 1000);

    var r = [];
    if (offset >= 86400) {
         var days = Math.floor(offset / 86400);
         offset -= days * 86400;
         r.push(plural('day', days));
    }
    if (offset >= 3600) {
         var hours = Math.floor(offset / 3600);
         offset -= hours * 3600;
         r.push(plural('hour', hours));
    }
    if (offset >= 60) {
         var minutes = Math.floor(offset / 60);
         offset -= minutes * 60;
         r.push(plural('minute', minutes));
    }
    if (offset != 0) {
         r.push(plural('second', offset));
    }
    return r.join(' ');
}
```

In the PHP code, you can set variable this way. And we'll leave time zones out of it for now, but they could be added as well just by specifying them.

```
echo "target_date = '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strotime('next Sunday 10am')) . "';\n";
```

Comment: How do I make this appear on page?  JSFiddle?

Comment: added it to my site and got "This page will refresh in NaN second"...same thing that appeared in JSfiddle.  I also fixed the typo in `strtotime`...There is apparently a mess up because its not recognizing it as a number...

Comment: Good catch, I left out a "t"

Comment: so any idea why its not recognizing it as a number?  Maybe a wrong format of date?  I dunno.  Its not working

Comment: The valid date format in javascript is 2015-03-25T12:00:00...you've got a space in yours.  I'm working on correcting the code now; however, keep getting EST because T in php is EST...haha.  Ugh

Comment: GOT IT!  `echo "target_date = '" . date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strotime('next Sunday 10am')) . "';\n";`   Works like a charm....

Comment: Might vary by browser then, good to know. What I had worked for me in Chrome 42 on Windows. For that format, you can use `date('c', ...)` but you'll need to either set the time zone or rely on having the server's time zone be the same as the visitor, the reference is at [PHP date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)